# Calculating average values of condition or receive values from a table for calculation in another table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I have a table with data (in this example the field "TSS"), a field time corresponds to the data for each point. I want to create a field with the mean values for each point all time values, without creating new table. Alternatively I would like to be informed of new table the mean values for each point if I fill the table with the measurements and present. Ηere create a numeric field (Double) named "avg" with the condition to enter a function (like AVERAGEIF of excel).

[image]

I am relatively new to GIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Summary_Statistics/00080000001z000000/) GP tool for that. Choose `TSS` as statistics field and `GR_NAME` (or other group field) as case field. Choose the `MEAN` statistic type.

You will get a resultant table which will contain the group name and the average value (among all rows found in your source points tables with that group name). Now you can use join this average value from the table back to the source points table (either [Add Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Add_Join/001700000064000000/) GP tool or right-click the layer in the table of contents > Joins and Relates).